# Force QGIS to not use 'Apply default' when running processing tasks

Tags: qgis

I have `Apply default value on update` on for some fields in the attributes form but I don't want it to update it when I run Field Calculator functions on any of the fields even though a different field maybe updated.

Rather than having to go into the form and ticking this off in each field everytime I need to run an algorithm, is there a setting somewhere to ignore the `Apply default` when using Field Calculator or running models/processing algorithms?

Ex

[image]

or

[image]